# Physical examples of topology class D

Tags: topological-insulators

In the course of writing a paper, I am compiling a list of various physical examples of the ten different topological symmetry classes<sup>1</sup>. For class D (broken time-reversal symmetry, particle-hole symmetry, and broken chiral symmetry), the commonly given example in two dimensions is a p-wave superconductor. I would first like to ask, Are any other examples know that are not superconductors? And as a follow-up, Are there non-superconductor examples in *one* dimension?

<sup>1</sup>[Periodic table of topological invariants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periodic_table_of_topological_invariants)

Comment: What did a web search with class D, one dimension, topological superconductor yield?

Comment: @TerryLoring I'm really looking for examples which aren't superconductors. I'll edit the question to make it clearer.